# How to track a dependency between 2 of my repositories

Tags: git, react-native, github, dependencies, repository

I have developed a mobile application with React Native and an API from which the mobile app can retrieve data. In order to version control my project I use two git repositories (one for the app and one for the API).

Sometimes I get confused when I have to write code to connect the application to the API.
For example, I could update the API with changes that make it not backward compatible with the current version of app, and forget to update the app to make it compatible with the new version of the API.

So my question is:
Is there a way to:

- declare a dependency between the repository of the app and the repository of the API ?
- And indicate that a particular version of the app (say 2.1.3) is compatible with particular versions of the API (say 1.X.X) ?
- And use Github's dependabot to automatically track compatibility issues between the two repositories ?

Answer (score 0):

I have difficulties understanding how the App and API could have dependencies that make them incompatible since they are 2 separate Apps, or are they installed together somehow?

In any case, if you need to integrate you API inside you App, you could make the API a dependency of the App itself.

In any case, Github has its own api, to wich you could make a request to get each repos info, but that feels like an app or a heavy workflow for such a task.

Comment: No the App and the API are completely separate. Let's say I update a route of the API, for example by changing the form of the URL or by changing the number of parameters. This update would make the app unable to communicate with this route until the app itself gets updated to be compatible with the new route.

Comment: This make more senses. In that case, there are multiple solution you could use.

1. UnitTest:
 depending on your language, you can setup a set of Test in your app, wich could include poking the API's Route and the use GithubActions to Build and Test your app on push to Master. you can read more [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/testing-overview)

2. You can prevent deprecation by redirecting your old route to the new route in case of a change, or add optional parameters, but then its an habbit to take instead I would say.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Alex and sorry for the delay. The first solution seems to be interesting, I am wondering if there is a way to make github notify/warn me automatically when there are compatibility issues. For example, let's say the API has been updated with a set of commits and the app is now no longer compatible and therefore has to be updated to connect with the API. Wouldn't it be great if github could detect that and notify me ?

Comment: Indeed, well there are solutions: You can set UnitTest in your API, wich you ties to the route you use in your app. On a Push/Merge on master, you can run Build then run tests and if the actions fails, Github sends you an email and notification.

Comment: Okay. And what if I don't test my repos at all (I'm not really used to testing) , are there any other ways ?